# how to link sugar crm campaigns module with parent child relationship

Tags: php, sugarcrm

How can I link the same module with itself in SugarCRM, For example Campaigns with a Parent/Child relationship, so that I can see related Campaigns.

I am new to sugar and working with 7.1.1

Can someone Help me pls..

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can  do it ,

1. Go to **Admin->studio->Your Module->Relationships**
2. `Add New Relationship.`
3. In **Related Module** select your current module .

It will create a relationship it should be 1 to many then , subpanel will create.

Comment: nope! ther eis only one-to--one option.. no one-to-many or many-to-many

Comment: then you have to , create custom subpanel or use relate field.